# Allow full stop in short summary of Sphinx docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

When writing the docstring for any python member, I have found that Sphinx will cut off the 'short summary' line at the first full stop it sees. This is annoying when I want to use things like 'e.g.' or 'i.e.' etc.

Example:

```
class Foo:
"""Short summary e.g. this bit gets left off.

Extended summary...
"""
```

Will produce:

```
Foo: 'Short summary e.g.'
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Note I am using Sphinx 1.6.6, unsure if this problem persists in other versions.

Comment: What happens if you upgrade Sphinx?

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on an isolated network and do not have this option :(